# File/Directory permissions for SFTP user

Tags: ssh, debian, sftp, users, chmod

After using the SSH quite a lot on my 1.5 week old Debian 6 VPS, I wanted to start uploading files through SFTP. I already tried that earlier, but with the root account, which isn't possible with SSH anymore due to security changes.

So I've made a separate user, let's call him ***sftpuser*** for now, who belongs to the group ***sftp***. 
He got a special entry in the sshd_config:

```
Match Group sftp
    ChrootDirectory /var/www
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    PasswordAuthentication yes
```

So, he is lucky and doesn't need a keyfile to connect, but he is limited to /var/www. Well, that works, I can login perfectly and view all files there. But as they are owned by the root user, he can not upload anything, which renders him quite useless.

On my journey through the wilds of file permissions I've read a lot of octal number combinations and weird workarounds, but nothing that quite fits. If I understand correctly, chmod can only be used to make a directory writeable to a certain user (***root*** in this case), group (guess what, ***root*** in this case \o/) or others. The 'best' idea I had to fix this issue without breaking both PHP-FPM and nginx was to add ***sftpuser*** to the ***root*** group. Even though I thought it would be a bad idea, that shouldn't be able to cause much havoc, as ***sftpuser*** is chrooted and unable to open a shell. But that didn't work anyway, I was not able to write to any files there, not even with ***sftpuser*** in the ***root*** group.

That said, I could really use help finding the right thing to use for my purpose. I don't expect a wall of text like I wrote here, just a little hint to point me in the right direction.

Comment: Beware that under linux, a process running as root can in most cases easily escape a chroot.

Comment: Yeah, I thought so, that's why I wrote it might be a bad idea. I removed ***sftpuser*** from the group right after the failed test.

Comment: I suggest that you take a look at Linux's ACLs.  I've never used them myself, but this sounds like the perfect case for them.  I think using a permission like `u:sftpuser:rwx` ought to do the trick, see a tutorial like http://sys-log.bencane.com/2012/05/acl-using-access-control-lists-on-linux/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did was to create a home volume (let's call it /sftphome) for the sftpuser which has to be owned by root and has the following permissions and ownership:

***/sftphome***

```
drwxr-xr-x    root root
```

Then the sftp home directory for sftpuser also has to be owned by root:

***/sftphome/sftpuser***

```
drwxr-xr-x    root root
```

Then create a directory where sftpuser can upload and download:

***/sftphome/sftpuser/upload***

```
drwx------  sftpuser sftpuser
```

Of course make sure ***/sftphome*** is properly configured:

```
ChrootDirectory /sftphome
```

The end result of this is that when sftpuser logs into the sftp server this user is directed to ***/sftphome/sftpuser*** and then has to cd into upload in order to be able to upload and download files.